# Edit nested resource ruby on rails 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, resources, nested, edit

I have an Opportunity model that has a nested resource called Link. I am trying to put in a way to edit my links:

```
<%= link_to "Edit Link", edit_opportunity_link_path(@opportunity, link)%>
```

However, when I click that link, I get the error:

undefined method `link_path'

The code snippet with the error is:

```
<%= form_for(@link) do |f| %> #This line is where the error is highlighted
<% if @link.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(@link.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this link from being     saved:</h2>
```

Can someone help? Thanks!

Comment: Could you post edit action? and your output of `rake routes`?

Comment: My links controller: def edit
  end I when I ran rake/routes, I get a very long list of routes, but there is a links#edit route @anonymousxxx